# Como exibir mensagem de que o app está processando

Tags: android

Tenho um método que é de complexidade de tempo exponencial e ele demora um pouco
pra processar, questão de trinta segundos em média. Contudo, durante esse tempo, o app trava e não dá sinal de vida. Queria mostrar uma mensagem de aguarde, tentei usar o Toast antes de iniciar o método, mas ele só aparece depois.

Comment: O correto é você usar uma classe AsyncTask, e para isso que deseja utilizar-se dos métodos do mesmo.

Comment: vlw, vou procurar saber mais dessa classe

Comment: @RBZ AsyncTask não é indicada para processamentos tão demoradas. Neste caso deverá usar-se Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor, FutureTask ou um Service.

Comment: @ramaral vou abrir um tópico sobre isso, é interessante. OBrigado mais uma vez ! Link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279330/quando-usar-asynctask-executor-threadpoolexecutor-futuretask-ou-um-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Respondendo sua pergunta:**

O correto é utilizar uma classe estendida da `AsyncTask` para exibir uma barra de progresso ou uma imagem, ou o que desejar, e processar em `background`.

Além disso, pelo fato do tempo de execução, como levantado pelo @ramaral (um usuário que conhece demais Android), criei o tópico: 
[Quando usar AsyncTask, ThreadPoolExecutor ou Service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279330/quando-usar-asynctask-executor-threadpoolexecutor-futuretask-ou-service)

**Por que utilizá-la ?**

Basicamente porque o Android após poucos segundos de processamento, ele pode reconhecer que seu APP parou, então se cria uma classe assíncrona que rode  `background`.

**Uma breve e rápida explicação sobre a classe AsyncTask:**

Propriedades da classe:
`AsyncTask<Parâmetros,Progresso,Resultado>`

Principais métodos da classe:

`onPreExecute`: irá executar antes de iniciar a tarefa (`doInBackground`);

`doInBackground`: irá executar a sua tarefa;

`onProgressUpdate`: irá executar durante a execução da sua tarefa;

`onPostExecute`: irá executar após o término da tarefa.

**Exemplo de um `progressBar` horizontal com classe AsyncTask:**

Classe `CalculoMatematico`:

```
public class CalculoMatematico extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    Context ctx;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public CalculoMatematico(Context ctx, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.progressBar.setProgress(0);
        this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        this.progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Seu código aqui


        // Aqui você seta o valor máximo
        this.progressBar.setMax(valor);

        // Aqui publica o valor atual, conforme atualiza
        publishProgress(valor);

    }
```

Classe `Main`:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarId);
        // Aqui você esconder sua progressBar ao iniciar ou fazer isso direto no xml
        this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void calcular() {
        CalculoMatematico calculo = new CalculoMatematico(this, this.progressBar);
        calculo.execute();
    }
```

XML `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.exemplo.recebejsonsqlite.Main">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

        ...Seus outros elementros...

</LinearLayout>
```

**Referências para leitura:**

[Documentação Oficial AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[Exemplo de uso da AsyncTask](https://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-asynctask-no-android/33481)